# How to delete a key or keys from the memory cache basis on particular pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, data-structures, memorycache

I have a method which generates our cache key which is a string like below:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> CacheKeys = new HashSet<string>();

public string Generate(int clientId, int processId)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("data:").Append("c:").Append(clientId).Append("::");
    sb.Append("pi::").Append(processId);

    // do I need to store everything in my CacheKeys?
    // or this can be improved so that I can fullfill below 3 requirements
    // CacheKeys.Add(sb.ToString());
    
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then this string gets cached in [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as a key along with their value (not shown here as it is not relevant).

```
_memoryCache.Set<T>(cacheKey, value, memoryCacheOptions);
```

I have a requirement where I need to delete a specific `key` or `keys` from the memory cache depending on below requirement-

- I need to delete specific `processId` + `clientId` key from the memory cache.
- I need to delete all keys matching specific `clientId` key from the memory cache regardless of `processId`.
- I also need to delete all the keys matching a particular `processId` key from the memory cache regardless of `clientId`.

Now after reading on SO and `MemoryCache` tutorial, it looks like there is no way to iterate over all the keys (or find keys matching particular regex pattern) and remove it from the cache.

**Problem Statement**

After going through various [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597133/14211530) it looks like I need to store my cache keys in separate data structure and then use that to remove it.

- How should I store my `cacheKey` in such a way in the above method so that I can remove a key basis on above 3 requirements easily by iterating this data structure or any thread safe data structure?
- Also the input structure which specifies what keys to remove (following above 3 pattern) is coming from some other service and that is not defined as well and I am pretty much open to represent in any format which can help me to do this task efficiently.

Basically I am trying to come up with an example for all my above three patterns by which I can remove the keys efficiently from `MemoryCache` which uses `RemoveByPattern` or `Remove` method. As of now I am not able to figure out on how to prepare an example or test cases for all those three cases which can use my `RemoveByPattern` or `Remove` method and clear the keys efficiently.

```
public void RemoveByPattern(MemoryCache memoryCache, string pattern)
{
    var keysToRemove = CacheKeys
        .Where(k => Regex.IsMatch(k, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var ktr in keysToRemove)
        Remove(memoryCache, ktr);
}

public void Remove(MemoryCache memoryCache, string key)
{
    memoryCache.Remove(key);
    CacheKeys.Remove(key);
}
```

How can I represent my input structure in such a way which can understand my above three requirements and then feed it to `RemoveByPattern` or `Remove` method easily?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. The goal is to make keys in `CacheKeys` consistent with keys in `MemoryCache`.

**Case 1: When adding a new key**

You need to add newly created key to both `MemoryCache` and `CacheKeys`.

```
_memoryCache.Set<T>(cacheKey, value, memoryCacheOptions);
CacheKeys.Add(cacheKey);
```

**Case 2: When removing an existing key**

Your implementation is good enough.

**Case 3: When a key is expired**

When a key is expired from `MemoryCache`, the key set is inconsistent between `MemoryCache` and `CacheKeys`. You need to implement a scheduled task running periodically in background to check and clean up `CacheKeys` (`MemoryCache` is the source of truth).

```
private void ConsolidateKeys()
{
    var invalidKeys = new List<string>();
    foreach (var key in CacheKeys)
    {
        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out var _))
        {
            invalidKeys.Add(key);
        }
    }
    foreach (var key in invalidKeys)
    {
        CacheKeys.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

**Note**

You need to consider thread safety of accessing `CacheKeys` since this is a multithreading scenario. Regarding data structure of `CacheKeys`, `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is recommended over `HashSet<T>`.

---

**Update**

To remove keys efficiently (assuming you mean speed), I will trade space for speed.

It is a bit complex, but you can define a set of `processId` named `ProcessIdMap`. The key is `processId`. The value is a set of `clientId` with the same `processId`  when generating cache keys. `ClientIdMap` is similar. (pseudo code)

```
ProcessIdMap = Map<processId, Set<clientId>>
ClientIdMap = Map<clientId, Set<cacheKey>>
```

**Case 1: when adding a new key**

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> CacheKeys = new HashSet<string>();
private static readonly Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> ProcessIdMap = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
private static readonly Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> ClientIdMap = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

private string BuildCacheKey(int clientId, int processId)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("data:").Append("c:").Append(clientId).Append("::");
    sb.Append("pi::").Append(processId);
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string AddToCache(int clientId, int processId)
{
    // Populate processId map
    if (!ProcessIdMap.TryGetValue(processId, out var clientIdSet))
    {
        clientIdSet = new HashSet<string>();
    }
    clientIdSet.Add(clientId);

    // Populate clientId map
    if (!ClientIdMap.TryGetValue(clientId, out var processIdSet))
    {
        processIdSet = new HashSet<string>();
    }
    processIdSet.Add(processId);

    var cacheKey = BuildCacheKey(clientId, processId);
    
    // Populate cache key store
    CacheKeys.Add(cacheKey);

    // Populate memory cache
    _memoryCache.Set<T>(cacheKey, value, memoryCacheOptions);

    return cacheKey;
}
```

**Case 2: when removing an existing key** (`RemoveClientId` method is similar)

```
public void RemoveProcessId(string processId)
{
    if (ProcessIdMap.TryGetValue(processId, out var clientIds))
    {
        foreach (var clientId in clientIds)
        {
            var cacheKey = BuildCacheKey(clientId, processId);

            // Remove from cache key store
            CacheKeys.Remove(cacheKey);

            // Remove from memory cache
            _memoryCache.Remove(cacheKey);

            // Remove from clientId map
            if (ClientIdMap.TryGetValue(clientId, out var processIdSet))
            {
                processIdSet.Remove(processId);
            }
        }

        // Remove from processId map
        ProcessIdMap.Remove(processId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion on using `ConcurrentDictionary`. I will look into that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but my confusion is how I am gonna use my `RemoveByPattern` or `Remove` method to achieve those 3 cases I have with `CacheKeys` set data structure or `ConcurrentDictionary` data structure? Do you think you can provide an example which can demonstrate on how to use those methods efficiently to achieve those 3 scenarios? As of now I am not able to figure out on how to prepare an example or test cases for all those 3 cases which can use my `RemoveByPattern` or `Remove` method.

Comment: For example: How can I represent my input structure in such a way which can understand my above three requirements and then feed it to `RemoveByPattern` or `Remove` method easily.

Comment: You still around? Any thoughts on how to setup an example for those three patterns which can demonstrate on how to remove the keys efficiently?

Comment: @user1950349 - Post is updated. Basically, the performance (speed-wise) will improve with two additional maps. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still trying to understand your suggestion. And yeah it is kinda complicated than I thought of earlier. In your example you suggested to use `ProcessIdMap` and `ClientIdMap` but I don't see they are being populated in your code or I missed something?

Comment: @user1950349 - I updated my post to make it clear. Populating happens when you call `AddToCache` method. The core idea is the same: no matter adding or removing cached item (along with cache key), `_memoryCache`, `CacheKeys`, `ProcessIdMap`, and `ClientIdMap` should be consistent.