# how to get all cache data which contains some keyword into it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, caching

I'm working with cache in c# (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory) as i'm storing multiple data into cache like below.

```
IMemoryCache cache;

cache.Set("xxxx_1", "xxxx");
cache.Set("xxxx_2", "xxxx");
cache.Set("xxxx_3", "xxxx");
```

and can also get data one by one.

```
Getcachedata = (string)cache.Get("xxxx_1")
```

but i want to get the data complete data which contains Key like xxxx into it.
i gone through many articles but didn't get help.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand - can you explain more, perhaps with some pseudo code what you want to achieve? what would your output look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677373

Comment: See if second answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673833/how-to-iterate-through-memorycache-in-asp-net-core?noredirect=1&lq=1) helps.

Comment: @RajeshG with the solution mentioned i'm getting null key var keys = cache.Get<List<string>>("abc.xyz"); but i can see key count with positive number

Answer (score 0):

Try write `CacheExtensions` class to customize a `GetCacheData` method like below:

```
public static class CacheExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> GetCacheData<TKey, TValue>(this IMemoryCache cache, TKey key)
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        var value = (TValue)(cache.Get(key) ?? default(TValue));
        data.Add(key, value);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then get the data result as shown:
[image]